# MySQL TimeZone Configuration

Tags: 22.04, mysql

Given:

- 22.04 / Eastern Time zone (New York)
- Instructions: https://github.com/curzon01/mqtt2sql#mysql-prerequisites

The instructions indicate:

> In order for MySQL to [handle time zones correctly](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html), make sure that
> the MySQL Server Time Zone Support is set up correctly (see also
> [Populating the Time Zone Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html#time-zone-installation)).

I loaded time-zone tables:

```
user@mysql:/usr/share/zoneinfo$  mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

and am not sure if the time zone must account for leap seconds :

```
user@mysql:/usr/share/zoneinfo$ mysql_tzinfo_to_sql --leap tz_file | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

Questions:

1. How can one verify / test that the time zone tables were loaded (first command)
2. How does one confirm it is necessary to account for leap seconds and perform the second command?

Comment: The general rule on GNU/Linux and the other Unixes is that if a command returns without reporting errors, it succeeded. If you want to be double sure, run it again and/\or check with MySQL support.

Comment: As for whether you need to account for leap seconds: only the developer of MQTT who pointed you to the MySQL site can tell you this. I suppose that if they stored wall clock times, you may need this. But there is no general answer to that question.